# Accessing database from custom modules

Tags: sugarcrm

I'm trying to create a custom module and I'm trying to get MY SQL access.

But i keep getting

> mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user
>   'scripts'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in
>   /home/scripts/public_html/crm/modules/PcPal/book-engineer.php on line
>   14

How do I access the data on the database when making a sugar module?

```
<?php if(!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry) die ('Not A valid Entry point'); ?>

<h2>Book an Engineer</h2>

<form method="POST" >
Search Last Name : <input type="text"  name="frm_last_name_search" value="<?php echo $_POST['frm_last_name_search']; ?>" />

<input type="submit"  value="Search"/>
</form>

<?php
$sql = 'SELECT first_name, last_name, primary_address_street FROM contacts WHERE last_name = \''.$_POST['frm_last_name_search'].'\'';

$results = mysql_query($sql);

while($this_result = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  print_r($this_result);
}


?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into using the bean methods for very common queries like this, as it's easier and more portable.

http://developers.sugarcrm.com/wordpress/2012/03/23/howto-using-the-bean-instead-of-sql-all-the-time/

Comment: That exactly what i'm looking for.  Do you have reference material so I can figure out how the bean objects works.

Comment: How can I search using the bean method so it bring multi records

Comment: See this comment on the post... http://developers.sugarcrm.com/wordpress/2012/03/23/howto-using-the-bean-instead-of-sql-all-the-time/#comment-669219400

Comment: Thanks. BTW I've brought 2 of your books to try and help me get into sugar easier.   I think you met my boss so it was easy to convince him to pay.

Comment: Jat Mann MD of PC PAL franchise in the UK

Answer (score 2):

Use the `global` object `$db` for doing the database actions.
If you have the module bean eg: `$bean = new Contact();`, you can use `$bean->db` instead of `global $db`.
Also while fetching from a table always use `deleted = 0`, as deleted items are marked as `1`.

```
global $db;
$sql = "SELECT first_name, last_name, primary_address_street FROM contacts 
WHERE last_name = '{$db->quote($_POST['frm_last_name_search']}' AND deleted = 0";

$rs = $db->query($sql);

while($row = $db->fetchByAssoc($rs))
{
  print_r($row);
}
```